# Finding non-spacing characters in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, thai

How do I check if a character in my `NSString` is a non-spacing character?

For example:

```
NSString *string3 = @"เบียร์เหล้า";
//                    12345678 <- only take up 8 spaces
```

The `NSString` length is 11, but actually the space that it occupies is 8.

In Java, they can check the character type using code below:

```
static boolean isMark(char ch)
{
    int type = Character.getType(ch);
    return type == Character.NON_SPACING_MARK ||
           type == Character.ENCLOSING_MARK ||
           type == Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK;
}
```

What about Objective-C?

Thanks to bdash.

```
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet nonBaseCharacterSet];

for (int i = 0; string3.length > i; i++)
{
    NSString *string = [string3 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    NSRange letterRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet];
    if (letterRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"non base character set");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"normal");
    }
}
```

You will find out which character that is not occupying space. 
Another way, you can find out the total non spacing character with code below.

```
NSString *newString = [[string3 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [[NSCharacterSet nonBaseCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

So for this example, the newString length is 3. That's what I'm looking for. 
Thanks people.

Comment: your string has only 1 space. so length is 11 after removing it.

Comment: I think I'll modify the question to make it clearer.

Comment: that is because of different unicode has different weight, like you are using malay, or some other language, and english has some other unicode. thats why

Comment: i also tested it with arabic language ,it shows different length

Comment: You can avoid allocating temporary strings like that by using `-[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:]`. You can give that method a range indicating which characters to consider in its search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`[NSCharacterSet nonBaseCharacterSet]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/nonBaseCharacterSet) to retrieve the set of characters in the Unicode mark category. `NSCharacterSet` provides the ability to test whether a given character is a member of the set, and `NSString` provides the ability to find particular characters within a string that are (or aren't) members of a given `NSCharacterSet`.